# Verify transaction on Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, paypal

I'm trying to get the transaction verification working for making an in-app purchase on Android in countries where Google Play isn't available.

When using the sandbox API everything seems to work well on my local Google App Engine dev server. The server sends a request to PayPal with the transaction ID and comes back with the JSON response containing the state of the transaction.

When I upload the code to Google App Engine, however, it instead uses the live API with corresponding credentials. When I do the transaction verification there, I get the following error from the Paypal REST SDK:

```
Response Code : 401 with response : {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
```

In the HttpServlet I use this to set the constant DEBUG to true or false:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    String dev = config.getServletContext().getServerInfo();
    if (dev.contains("Development")) {
        Constants.DEBUG = true;
    } else {
        Constants.DEBUG = false;
    }
}
```

The transaction ID is verified with the code below. It gets the access token for making the API call and then verifies the transaction id. I also create a custom config which sets `GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE` to true and `MODE` to sandbox or live depending on the `DEBUG` constant (this is because I couldn't get the `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("sdk_config.properties")` working as it gave an Access denied error).

```
public static String getAccessToken() throws PayPalRESTException {
    String clientSecret, clientID;
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        clientSecret = Constants.CLIENT_SECRET_SANDBOX;
        clientID = Constants.CLIENT_ID_SANDBOX;
    } else {
        clientSecret = Constants.CLIENT_SECRET_LIVE;
        clientID = Constants.CLIENT_ID_LIVE;
    }
    return new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret,
            getPaypalConfig()).getAccessToken();
}

public static Map<String, String> getPaypalConfig() {
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(com.paypal.core.Constants.GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE,
            String.valueOf(true));
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        config.put(com.paypal.core.Constants.MODE,
                com.paypal.core.Constants.SANDBOX);
    } else {
        config.put(com.paypal.core.Constants.MODE,
                com.paypal.core.Constants.LIVE);
    }
    return config;
}

public static boolean payPalVerifier(String saleId)
        throws PayPalRESTException {
    if (accessToken == null) {
        accessToken = Utils.getAccessToken();
        apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        apiContext.setConfigurationMap(Utils.getPaypalConfig());
    }
    boolean completed = false;
    Payment pay = Payment.get(apiContext, saleId);

    for (Transaction transaction : pay.getTransactions()) {
        for (RelatedResources relatedResources : transaction
                .getRelatedResources()) {
            if (com.pixplicity.Constants.DEBUG) {
                completed = relatedResources.getSale().getState()
                        .equals("completed")
                        || relatedResources.getSale().getState()
                                .equals("pending");
            } else {
                completed = relatedResources.getSale().getState()
                        .equals("completed");
            }
        }
    }
    return completed;
}
```

How do I solve this problem?